# UI not updating when filtering data with pipe

Tags: javascript, angular

HTML:

```
<div class="box" *ngFor="let game of gameData | gameFilter: searchText | slice:1; let i = index">
```

Pipe:

```
export class GameFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: any, searchText: string): any[] {
    if (!items) {
      return [];
    }
    if (!searchText) {
      return items;
    }
    searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();

    let timeout;
    if (timeout) { clearTimeout(timeout); }
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      performSearch(searchText);
    }, 2000);

    function performSearch(txt) {
      if (txt.length < 5) { return; }
      const filtered = items.filter((e: any, i: number) => {
        if (i > 0) {
          return e.title.toLowerCase().includes(txt);
        }
      });
      console.log('filtered ', filtered); // logs data after change
      return filtered;
    }
  }
}
```

I see the data logged after filter but the UI doesn't update. I tried both `pure and impure` but still doesn't work.

I have data logged this way:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {title: "LittleBigPlanet PS Vita", platform: "PlayStation Vita", score: 9, genre: "Platformer", editors_choice: "Y"}
1: {title: "LittleBigPlanet PS Vita -- Marvel Super Hero Edition", platform: "PlayStation Vita", score: 9, genre: "Platformer", editors_choice: "Y"}
2: {title: "New Little King's Story", platform: "PlayStation Vita", score: 5.8, genre: "RPG", editors_choice: "N"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pipe is not returning anything. Your inner `performSearch` function looks like it performs a search, but wrapping it inside a `setTimeout()` causes your pipe to return undefined.

[Here's a test demonstrating.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-jn4ggh?file=app%2Fgame-filter.pipe.spec.ts)

It's unclear why you're using `setTimeout()`, so I recommend removing it.

```
  transform(items: any, searchText: string): any[] {
    if (!items) {
      return [];
    }
    if (!searchText) {
      return items;
    }
    const txt = searchText.toLowerCase();
    if (txt.length < 5) { return; }
    const filtered = items.filter((e: any, i: number) => {
      return e.title.toLowerCase().includes(txt);
    });
    console.log('filtered ', filtered);
    return filtered;
  }
```

Comment: but I don't understand why it isn't with timeout ?

Comment: setTimeout() simply executes a function after a specified number of milliseconds. Your pipe will not wait for it to execute.

Comment: probably I can try out with promises I guess

Comment: Have a look at Angular async pipe if you've got async transforms
https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Answer (score 0):

Your function **performSearch** returns the filtered result, but your pipe doesn't.

So, you have to return the result also

```
timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    return performSearch(searchText);
}, 2000);
```